# Wordpress prevent hook from firing if page is visited by a bot

Tags: php, wordpress, web-crawler

I created an sms otp system for a WordPress website via a plugin. The flow is like this:

Open link from a received email -> go to website, on landing on the page, an sms is sent -> resolve the otp -> user automatically logged in.

However, I realized that if you send the link to someone, in a slack message i.e/, or other popular application, the page receive a ping from their bot, an my otp request is sent.

I would like a way to prevent this. My first idea was too use user-agent to block the popular applications bots but it looks weak and their is difficult too maintain.

```
$social_bots = array(
    '/facebookexternalhit/i',
    '/Twitterbot/i',
    '/LinkedInBot/i',
    '/Instagram/i',
    '/Pinterest/i'
);

$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

// REGEX condition to ensuring the user agent is not in the above.
```

Any ideas, i'd rather not use any additional libraries and composer stuff?

Comment: After the user clicked the link in the mail and arrives on your site, make them submit a form with method="post" first, and use that to trigger your action. Convention is for bots not to trigger POST requests.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 suggestions

1. check not bots but browsers. Validate like 10-15 most popular and send sms if ok
2. trigger sending with js after timeout of 5 seconds with fetch or axios (add some preloader for user to understand that smth is processing)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but your solutions may compromise UX (loading time, etc..). But I guess there is no way around...

Comment: Don`t see in what way it can influence loading time

First method would be same in time
Second method can be done in background, without preventing user actions on site, i suggested preloader only for visual notification that smth is processing, you can simply put small label in right bottom corner (like recaptcha3 and after successful sending sms change text to something like "Login with your sms" and open modal on click)

Comment: Indeed, the first method is already a solution that I use, but is not ideal, since it will need to be maintained and is not protected for any bots which are less popular.

The second method you propose wait for 5 seconds. Because its JS, it will not delay the page loading time but the user will still need to wait the remaining amount of time which is not desirable. Adding a recaptcha is also less preferred as It will separate the user to its goal with additional clicks. My main goals is to create a quick and easy login for lazy customers. Thank you for your ideas.